# Invalid SecureWindow API, toString was blacklisted : Source Error in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, locker-service

I am new to Lightning. I have created Lightning component and a controller.

Lightning component code:

```
<aura:component >
<ui:button press="{!c.doInit}">
    <div class="testClass">Click Me</div>
</ui:button>
```

Controller:

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(window.toString());
    console.log(document.toString());        
    var div = document.querySelector(".testClass");
    console.log(div.toString());
    console.log(div.parentNode.innerHTML);
}
```

})

But on saving controller, it throws the error: 
**FIELD_INTEGRITY_ERROR**

```
Failed to save LLServiceOnController.js: ESLINT_ERROR: {c:LLServiceOn - CONTROLLER} line:col [3:21] --> Invalid SecureWindow API, toString was blacklisted : Source
```

how can i rectify this error. Can anybody help me on this!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't take everything in the window and output it in the console as a string. It's referring to this line:

```
console.log(window.toString());
```

Comment: above controller will be saving on 39 version. but why current(43) version getting error. how can i solve this error

Comment: The issue is because of Locker Service. You're constrained to staying within your own memory space and not trying to get outside of it by touching the larger  DOM of the Window. Remove that line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

The function `toString()` is exposed on window by [Locker Service](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV). The new linting rules are probably too strict, we'll need to double-check.

You can force a `toString()` by concatenation, something eslint will not catch:

```
console.log(window + '');
```